# In Jinja how to access Macro parameters in a set block that runs SQL?

Tags: jinja2, dbt

Hi all I'm currently writing Jinja macro that runs a sql query based on some parameters passed to it.
I'm having some issue with the macro definition itself. I cannot find a way to use the macros paramters within the set block. It interprets the value as literally 'col1' not the value stored in it.

How can I run a SQL query within the macro that uses my parameters stored value?

How I run the macro:

```
WITH DRIVER 
AS(
    SELECT
    'apple' as col1
)

SELECT
    {{ select_test('col1') }} as output
FROM
    DRIVER
```

The macro definition is shown below:

```
{% macro select_test(val1) %}

    {% set query_to_run%}
        select
         concat({{val1}},'banana')
    {% endset %}

    {% set results = run_query(query_to_run) %}

    {% if execute %}
    {# Return the first column #}
    {% set results_list = results.columns[0].values() %}
    {% else %}
    {% set results_list = [] %}
    {% endif %}

    {{ return(results_list) }}

{% endmacro %}
```

I currently get the following output:
col1banana

My expected output:
applebanana

note: edited for clarity

Comment: Thanks for the minimal reproducible example! Great job writing this question.

Answer (score 0):

You're very close -- I think you're confused by the nested nature of this query.

I suspect when you created this example, you didn't include a set of quotes that is in your original query. This query will return `col1banana` if `col1` is double-quoted (either in the macro or the model), and will return a Database Error otherwise:

```
select
    concat('{{ val1 }}','banana')
-- {{ select_test('col1') }} returns 'col1banana'

select
    concat({{ val1 }}, 'banana')
-- {{ select_test("'col1'") }} returns 'col1banana'

select
    concat({{ val1 }}, 'banana')
-- {{ select_test('col1') }} raises a Database Error: column "col1" does not exist
```

The last example is always going to be a database error, since it compiles to this:

```sql
select
    concat(col1, 'banana')
```

and there is no `from` clause in your `query_to_run`, so `col1` can't exist.

Most macros don't use `run_query` and are just shortcuts for snippets of sql. Those then get templated back into the model query and executed against your database when you build your model.

A macro to concatenate a string onto a column name is as simple as:

```sql
{% macro cat_banana(column_name) %}
concat({{ column_name }}, 'banana')
{% endmacro %}
```

And then you call it from your model:

```sql
WITH DRIVER 
AS(
    SELECT
    'apple' as col1
)

SELECT
    {{ cat_banana('col1') }} as output
FROM
    DRIVER
```

Then after `dbt run -s my_model`, if you `select * from my_model` you'll get `applebanana`.

Comment: This is not quite the answer I'm looking for. Suppose the macro must run a SQL query and within that query, it must also contain the value stored in the parameter. 

Relating this back to my example. When I invoke the macro. `{{ select_test('col1') }}`
I'm expecting it to pass in the value 'apple' from my driver CTE.
Then in the macro I expect the {{val1}} below to be substituted with the value 'apple'

{% set query_to_run%}
        select
         concat({{val1}},'banana')
    {% endset %}

How can this be achieved instead of having the {{val1}} be substituted for 'col1'?